# this.router.navigate['/catalog']; not working in stackblitz project

Tags: angular, routes, stackblitz

I am beginner in Angular.

I would like to route to a page from the component.ts code (not from the template).

I started from a stackblitz and forked it, but it's not working:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-kbgxr6?file=app/app.component.ts

I just added this to the existing code:

```js
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  toCompA() {
    console.log('to comp a');
    // this is not working ?
    this.router.navigate['/catalog'];
    console.log('to comp a end');
  }
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the method. This is essentially accessing property `/catalog` of object `this.router.navigate` and not doing anything with the result:

```js
this.router.navigate['/catalog'];
```

The right syntax is:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/catalog']);
```

Comment: Shame on me to ask such a silly question, but nevertheless Thank you!